# Conflicts with a simple loop to keep record of row switches in matlab

Tags: matlab

I made a loop to keep track of loop switches.

```
C = zeros(i,2);

for q=1:i

    if any(A(q,:)~= K(q,:))

        %Save the row at which B is different(aka Ending Position)
        C(q,2) = q;
        for a=1:i
            if A(a,:) == K(q,:)
            C(q,1) = a;
            end;
        end
    end

end
```

---

`A` and `B` are the two matrices. `C` is the one storing the switches. But for some reason the last row of `C` has a 3, which is not supposed to happen since [2 3 1] = [2 3 1]

```
A =

     1     3     1
     3     2     1
     2     3     1
K =

    3.0000    2.0000    1.0000
    1.0000    3.0000    1.0000
    2.0000    3.0000    1.0000

C =

     2     1
     1     2
     0     3
```

Comment: What exactly is a "loop switch"?  This isn't obvious in your code or your description of the problem.  We're here to help you but we're not here to guess what you're trying to do.

Comment: Oh sorry, just switching rows. In this case, between A and K, row 1 and 2 switched.

Comment: Aha, ok.  That makes perfect sense.  I've placed an answer.  Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this statement:

```
if A(a,:) == K(q,:)
    C(q,1) = a;
end
```

I suspect you only want this statement to happen if **all** of the elements between `A(a,:)` and `K(q,:)` are true.  As such, you must use the [`all`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/all.html) command to ensure that this is true.  By omitting the `all`, this statement will be true **if at least one element between these two vectors is true**, which explains the unexpected behaviour.  As such:

```
if all(A(a,:) == K(q,:))
    C(q,1) = a;
end
```

With your example inputs, this is what I get for `C`:

```
C =

 2     1
 1     2
 0     0
```

The last row being `[0 0]` symbolizes that the third rows between `A` and `K` were the same and not swapped, as nothing was assigned to the last row of `C` during that loop.

Comment: Amazing, it works! thank you. Yes, haha I assumed that     
A(a,:) == K(q,:) meant that if both rows in their entirety were equal it would return true. Thanks for the suggestion of the all function!